# Getting Syntax error on token "{", SwitchLabels expected after this token. Trying to use user input in switch-statements

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am very new to Java and trying to implement user input into a switch statement. I am getting "the Syntax error on token "{", SwitchLabels expected after this token" error at the beginning of my Switch-Statement". Any help would be awesome. Thanks. (Btw first post on stackoverflow so sorry if I messed up the formatting)

```
import java.util.*;

class FahrenheitToCelsiusBothInput {

public static void main(String[] args) {
float Fahrenheit = 32;
float Celsius = 0;

Scanner option = new Scanner(System.in);

int userInput = option.nextInt();
switch(userInput) {                      //Getting "Syntax error on token "{", SwitchLabels expected after this token"
System.out.println("Do You Want to Enter Fahrenheit or Celsius: ");
case Fahrenheit:
        System.out.println("Enter temperature in Fahrenheit: ");
        Fahrenheit = in.nextInt();
        Fahrenheit = (float) ((Fahrenheit - 32) / 1.8000);
        System.out.println("Temperature in Celsius = " + Fahenheit);  System.out.println("Thank You! ");
   break; 
case Celsius:
        System.out.println("Enter temperature in Celsius: ");
        Celsius = in.nextInt();
        Celsius = (float) ((Celsius * 1.8000) + 32);
        System.out.println("Temperature in Fahrenheit = " + Celsius);  System.out.println("Thank You! ");
    break;  
default:
        System.out.println("Something went wrong! ");
    break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That specific problem has to do with this line of code:

```
System.out.println("Do You Want to Enter Fahrenheit or Celsius: ");
```

It should be placed before the switch.  I see another problem that will come up after this, however.

Your case statement will be comparing a float to an int.  You can just change it to case 1: and case 2: (or case 0 and case 32) to eliminate this problem.  The better way to do it would with strings or a user menu, though.

**Fixed code below**

```
import java.util.*;

class FahrenheitToCelsiusBothInput {

public static void main(String[] args) {
float Fahrenheit = 32;
float Celsius = 0;

Scanner option = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Do You Want to Enter Fahrenheit or Celsius: ");
int userInput = option.nextInt();

switch(userInput) {                      //Getting "Syntax error on token "{", SwitchLabels expected after this token"
case 0:
        System.out.println("Enter temperature in Fahrenheit: ");
        Fahrenheit = option.nextInt();
        Fahrenheit = (float) ((Fahrenheit - 32) / 1.8000);
        System.out.println("Temperature in Celsius = " + Fahrenheit);  System.out.println("Thank You! ");
   break; 
case 1:
        System.out.println("Enter temperature in Celsius: ");
        Celsius = option.nextFloat();
        Celsius = (float) ((Celsius * 1.8000) + 32);
        System.out.println("Temperature in Fahrenheit = " + Celsius);  System.out.println("Thank You! ");
    break;  
default:
        System.out.println("Something went wrong! ");
    break;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Adjusted the code so it actually works.

Comment: Hey I am having another problem if you could help me @rctillotson. I am getting these errors with the code above.                                Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException    
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)

Comment: That was my error.  You need to put "System.out.println("Do You Want to Enter Fahrenheit or Celsius: ");" "BEFORE int userInput = option.nextInt();"  I will change the code above to reflect this.